# Class styling on a custom component in Svelte does not register

Tags: svelte, sapper

I am using Svelte/Sapper templae and added Attractions UI, but I cannot apply any class/styles to their custom components, like so:

```
<TextField class='search-box' type='search' />
<style>
    .search-box {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

I get

> Unused CSS selector ".search-box"

The only way to make it work so far for me was to apply the `:global` modifier on the style.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is not currently possible in Svelte. The `class` prop is not treated as special in Svelte, so it does not leak the style scope into the child component, especially since there does not have to be one root element in the child component (unlike in Vue.js, for instance).

Therefore, you **cannot** add styles in the parent component and expect them to reach the child component. Your only option is to use the `:global` modifier or add the styles to a global stylesheet (included directly in the HTML, not in a Svelte component)

Note that you can combine `:global` and scoped styles. For example, consider:

```
<div class='local'>
    <TextField class='search-box' type='search' />
</div>

<style>
    .local :global(.search-box) {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

This way, the styles are not leaked to other components and are still scoped to this component only.

Comment: Given the way svelte scopes classes this seems to be the only way you can style a child component without creating truly global styles. Just be sure to add `{...$$props}` to your child component so the class is applied :)

Comment: @stwilz either that or export a prop called "class" (which we do in Attractions).
This is actually one of the few case where I personally miss Vue's `inheritAttrs` :D

Comment: You mean the old' `let className = ''; export { className as class};`? 
That would also work but it's still my least favourite things about Svelte :(

Answer (score 18):

The problem here is that Svelte has no way of knowing that the `class` property refers to a CSS class here or even *where* to apply this class.  Something to not forget is that the following are all valid Svelte components:

```html
<span>Hello World</span>
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
```

```
Hello World
```

In the first example, it should *probably* be on the span, but where should the class go in the second example, the first or second span ? Or maybe both ? And what about the last example where there is no DOM element at all, you cannot add a class to a textnode.

Because of this your class is marked as *unused* by Svelte and removed during compilation.  This is inline with Svelte *Single File Component* philosophy where all styling for a component is included in the same file. While your construction is counter to that it is sometimes a valid approach, this is what the `:global` is for.

Note that you can export a `class` property from TextField and apply to the element of your choice, you would still need to mark the class as global though:

```html
<script>
    // You must do this because class is a reserved keyword in JavaScript
    let className;
    export { className as class };
</script>
<div>
  <p>
    <span class={className}>...</span>
  <p>
  <button>...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: > "you can export a class property from TextField and apply to the element of your choice".

This is exactly what the mentioned Attractions library does. I believe the question was about how to use such component with such prop without having to use the `:global` modifier

Comment: Which is impossible, and my answers explains **why** it is not possible.

Comment: I'm having trouble using $$props.class inside a library which, as I import it from npm, errors with "The $ prefix is reserved, and cannot be used for variable and import names" so this approach I guess would work but I'm not sure how do you define a default value with this approach? As now I get annoying warnings about undeclared props